# Is every matrix that sends spheres to spheres of the same radius an orthogonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, orthogonal-matrices

Matrices send spheres to ellipsoids.  Orthogonal matrices send spheres to spheres of the same radius.

Is the converse true? Is every matrix that sends spheres to spheres of the same radius an orthogonal matrix?

If so: Let $A$ be a matrix.  Let $P$ be the set of vectors such that for all $p \in P, \|Ap\| = \|p\|$.  According to the above, $A$ is orthogonal iff the complement of $P$ is empty.  If $A$ is not orthogonal, can we somehow describe the "size" or nature of $P$ versus its compliment?

Comment: Polarity identities (or law of cosines actually) imply that a linear transformation preserving length also preserves angles, and hence is orthogonal. Did you search the site?

Comment: You should mention the underlying field. I guess it is $\mathbb{R}$ since you said "orthogonal". So, if $O\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and $Ox$ has length $1$ provided $x$ has length $1$, then $Ox$ has length $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$ provided $x$ has length $\lambda$. (since $O\lambda x=\lambda Ox$). Then for all $x$, $x^TO^TOx=\langle Ox, Ox\rangle=\langle x,x\rangle=x^Tx=x^TI_nx$, i.e. $x^T(O^TO-I_n)x=0$. What can you say about a symmetric matrix $A$ s.t. $x^TAx\equiv 0$ for all $x$?

Comment: @Asigan If for all $x, x^TAx = 0$, then all real eigenvalues of $A$ must clearly be $0$.  If $A$ is symmetric, then it has an eigenbasis of eigenvectors, and hence must be the $0$ matrix, implying that $O^TO = I$ and $O$ is orthogonal!

Comment: That is correct and hence completes the solution. Your observation is nice!